# Find minimum and maximum values of a function in a closed and bounded subset

Tags: functions, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

I need to find minimum and maximum for this one:

$f(x,y)=xy$, $(|x|^a+|y|^a\leq1)$, $a>0$

I tried to use Lagrange multipliers but got stuck.

Comment: First work on multiple open that shape your set. Then study independently at the border.

Comment: Note that $(x,y)$ is a maximiser **iff** $(x,-y)$ is a minimiser. Also, the constraint set is not differentiable on the axis for $\alpha \le 1$, so some care is needed there.

Comment: It is sufficient to work in the first quadrant, since the function $ \ xy \ $ has  symmetry about the origin.  The Lagrange equations you presumably found are $ \ y \ = \ \alpha·x^{\alpha - 1} \ , \ \ x \ = \ \alpha·y^{\alpha - 1} \ $ .  Solving for $ \ \lambda \ $ , we have $$ \frac{x}{\alpha·y^{\alpha - 1}} \ = \ \frac{y}{\alpha·x^{\alpha - 1}} \ $$  For $ \ x \ \neq \ 0 \ , \ y \ \neq \ 0 \ , $ cross-multiplying these ratios and simplifying leads to $ \ x^{\alpha} \ = \ y^{\alpha} \ $ and the extrema and their locations follow as described in the comments here and the answers below.

Comment: (concluding)  We see that the only critical point in the interior is (0,0) and that $ \ xy \ = \ 0 $ everywhere on the coordinate axes.  So there is no extremum in the interior and we need only discuss the region's boundary.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM $$xy\leq|xy|\leq\left(\frac{|x|^a+|y|^a}{2}\right)^{\frac{2}{a}}\leq\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{2}{a}}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{a}},$ which says that we got a maximal value.

By the same way we can got a minimal value: $-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{2}{a}}.$

Comment: Ignore my comment. Fuzzy thinking. The axes are not even in the feasible set. Shows the danger of reasoning by picture.

Answer (score 0):

You're set is

$$ \mathbb{D}_\alpha \triangleq \mathbb{B}(0,1) $$

The disc associated to the following norm:

$$ || \ ||_{\alpha} :(x,y)\to |x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha $$

So first determine the reunion of the open set which constitute your disc then add the border.

So you have in a open :

$$ \partial_1f(x,y)=y$$
$$ \partial_2f(x,y)=x$$

**The only critical point in the open is $(0,0)$**

On the border we get for instance (I consider first case of $ 0 \leq x $ and $ 0 \leq y$ ) so $ y=(1-x^\alpha)^\frac{1}{\alpha} $

So in these conditions:

$$ f(x,y)=g(x)\triangleq x(1-x^\alpha)^\frac{1}{\alpha}  $$

Differentiating $g$:

$$ g'(x)= (1-x^\alpha)^\frac{1}{\alpha}(1-\dfrac{\alpha x^\alpha}{1-x^{\alpha}}) $$

You shall find roots ! (not complicated)

Comment: True ! Hence the need of defining clearly your set of work , depending on $\alpha$.

Comment: Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, the objective is to optimize the value of $x_1x_2\cdots x_n$ subject to 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\,\left|x_i\right|^{a_i}\leq m\,,$$
where $m,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.  The OP's question is a particular case where $n=2$, $x_1=x$, $x_2=y$, $a_1=a_2=a$, and $m=1$.

By the [Weighted AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality),
$$\begin{align}
m&\geq \sum_{i=1}^n\,\left|x_i\right|^{a_i}=\sum_{i=1}^n\,\frac{\frac{1}{a_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}\Biggl(a_i\,\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_i}\Big)\,\left|x_i\right|^{a_i}\Biggr)
\\&\geq \prod_{i=1}^n\,\Biggl(a_i\,\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_i}\Big)\,\left|x_i\right|^{a_i}\Biggr)^{\frac{\frac{1}{a_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}}\\&=\left(\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}\Big)^{{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}}\,\Big(\prod_{i=1}^n\,a_i^{\frac{1}{a_i}}\Big)\,\Big|\prod_{i=1}^n\,x_i\Big|\right)^{\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}}\,.
\end{align}$$
Thus,
$$\Big|\prod_{i=1}^n\,x_i\Big|\leq \frac{m^{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}}{\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}\Big)^{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}\,\Big(\prod_{i=1}^n\,a_i^{\frac{1}{a_i}}\Big)}\,,$$
or
$$-\frac{m^{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}}{\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}\Big)^{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}\,\Big(\prod_{i=1}^n\,a_i^{\frac{1}{a_i}}\Big)}\leq \prod_{i=1}^n\,x_i\leq +\frac{m^{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}}{\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}\Big)^{\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}\,\Big(\prod_{i=1}^n\,a_i^{\frac{1}{a_i}}\Big)}\,.$$
The equality holds if and only if 
$$x_i=\pm\left(\frac{m}{a_i\,\sum_{j=1}^n\,\frac{1}{a_j}}\right)^{1/a_i}\,.$$

In the OP's case, we have
$$|xy|\leq 2^{-2/a}\text{ or }-2^{-2/a}\leq xy\leq +2^{-2/a} \,.$$
The minimum occurs iff $(x,y)=\pm\left(2^{-1/a},-2^{-1/a}\right)$, whereas the maximum occurs iff $(x,y)=\pm\left(2^{1/a},2^{1/a}\right)$.